# How to config in IDE of Visual Studio 2008 to compile STLPORT without command line?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, stlport

I want to config VS2008 to compile STLPORT without command line build.
Following these docs of STLPORT, there is only way to compile STLPORT with VS2008 in command line, like: configure, nmake clean install and so on.
But there is only one word in these docs:

```
"IDE users may have to do something special, 
like add environment variables (for Microsoft) or 
install additional compiler components (for Metrowerks), 
before they can use their command line compilers "
```

I wanna know how? Any help for highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What for? What advantage would compiling through the IDE give vs. using nmake?

Comment: Compile STLPORT with other source code without any libs of STLPORT.

Comment: Fair enough! +1. I think that getting it to build in the IDE (and be automatically linked against) would probably take at least a couple days, though, whereas building it on the command line (and linking against it manually) is well documented and would be much easier/faster. I'm assuming that you won't be modifying (and therefore needing to recompile) STLPORT often, if at all.